# What is the origin of the term, “to 86 someone”?

Tags: phrase-origin

I came across a phrase, “86 to sb.” in the following paragraph of an article titled “The owner of the Red Hen explains why she asked Sarah Huckabee Sanders to leave,” in the Washington Post (June 23), that comes with a picture of an actual paycheck issued by the restaurant showing the code, “86” above the name of a recipient.

The paragraph reads;

> If you ever heard the term “**to 86 someone,**” it comes from the
> restaurant industry – code to refuse service, or alternatively to take
> an item off the menu.

I’m curious to know why the number 86 came to represent the refusal of service at service establishments. Does someone know the provenance?

**Addendum**

I noticed that my post duplicates with the similar question posted in 2011, but I dont' think I find a convincing source of its provenance (first appearance, sources, usage trend, currency). It seems that the word gained recency and life with the restaurant owner's refusal to serve  Sarah Huckabee in her Mexican restaurant. Is there any new source of its origin than  ones I saw on the previous post?

I checked both Cambridge and Oxford online dictionaries for this word.
Cambridge doesn't carry this word.

Oxford Dictionaries define "eighty six" as;

> 1.(informal) Eject or bar someone from a restaurant, bar etc.
>
> 2.Reject, discard or cancel.

Origin:

1930s (as a noun) used in restaurants and bars to indicate that a menu item is not available or that a customer is not to be served. Perhaps rhyming slang for *nix*, which sounds like a bit overstretched assumption to me.

The currency of the word or number - 86 is unexpectedly high based on google Ngram.

The usage can track back to earlier than 1800 (at 0.002% level) and keeps rising up to 0.00672% level in 2000.

Comment: I've always understood "86 someone" to be gangland slang for killing them.  I vaguely suspect a nautical origin.  But [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=86) gives a different slant, somewhere between your understanding and mine.

Comment: A good reason to eat meals at home.

Comment: It seems the other question should be closed as a duplicate of this one. The other question lacks context and research.

Comment: @JJJ the answers on the older question are much better though. There's no comparison.

Comment: Yoichi, I hope the Google Ngram results that you speak of do not refer to the number 86 in isolation. The vast majority of instances will refer to the mathematical number and NOT to its slang meaning.

Comment: Mari-Lou A.  I wonder how meaningfhul  86  is as a mathmatical or scientific term.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you type in the numbers 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, and 87  in Google Ngrams, you get [this result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=27%2C37%2C47%2C57%2C67%2C77%2C+87%2C&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C27%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C37%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C47%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C57%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C67%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C77%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C87%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: If you look at the results at the bottom of the page, you find instances where 87 refers to the year or just the number https://www.google.com/search?q=%2287%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en I think the Ngram you mention in your answer is simply referring to it as a number.

Comment: Then do we have 1,2,3,4 .... to thousands and a, b, c, d, ...., A,B, C, D, ... to Z and other random combinations of numbers like 86  on Ngram, though I don't feel like trying?

Comment: @Mari-LouA This seems to be a better answer https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2018/06/a-restaurant-eighty-sixed-sarah-huckabee-sanders-what-does-that-mean/563588/ especially concerning how "86" started to be applied to people.

Answer (score 0):

**eighty six**, an article from  [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-eig1.htm) is revealing.  Origins vary from a bar, a drunk, restaurant practices, British shipping, a New York streetcar or just a rhyme?

And here's another reference to Chumley's Bar and "no more for you."  [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=86)

And the [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/eighty-six) of **eighty six**: to eliminate ~1936. My sense is of origin lies here, and the other posted references lend 'color'.

Comment: Are the first two sentences, actually sentences? There are no verbs? **Eighty-six Worldwide Words** literally means there are 86 words worldwide.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  aye!